# Rails add scope to Mongoid criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, named-scope

I have a model with different scopes

```
class Contact
  include Mongoid::Document

  scope :active
  scope :urgent
  scope :no_one_in_charge
```

In some of my controller, I pull the active scopes

*my_controller.rb*

```
def my_action
  @contacts = Contact.active
```

Now in the view, I'd like to generate many tables with more specific scoping

*my_action.html.erb*

```
<h3>Unassigned</h3>

<%= @contacts.[how Do I add the :no_one_in_charge scope ?] %>

<h3>Urgent</h3>

<%= @contacts.[how Do I add the :urgent scope ?] %>
```

Comment: you can chain scopes right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [chain scopes](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/scopes.html). So your code will be

```
<h3>Unassigned</h3>

<%= no_one_in_charge_contacts @contacts %>

<h3>Urgent</h3>

<%= urgent_contacts @contacts %>
```

So, you shouldn't query inside the view, so make 2 helpers for those. Go to the `helpers/my_action_helper.rb` and write :

```
def urgent_contacts contact
  contact.urgent
end

def no_one_in_charge_contacts contact
  contact.no_one_in_charge
end
```